# Python: Why can't I get my decorator to work?

Tags: python, decorator

This works now for those new to this question:

```
class ensureparams(object):
    """

    Used as a decorator with an iterable passed in, this will look for each item
    in the iterable given as a key in the params argument of the function being
    decorated. It was built for a series of PayPal methods that require
    different params, and AOP was the best way to handle it while staying DRY.


    >>> @ensureparams(['name', 'pass', 'code'])
    ... def complex_function(params):
    ...     print(params['name'])
    ...     print(params['pass'])
    ...     print(params['code'])
    >>> 
    >>> params = {
    ...     'name': 'John Doe',
    ...     'pass': 'OpenSesame',
    ...     #'code': '1134',
    ... }
    >>> 
    >>> complex_function(params=params)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: Missing from "params" dictionary in "complex_function": code
    """
    def __init__(self, required):
        self.required = set(required)

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not kwargs.get('params', None):
                raise KeyError('"params" kwarg required for {0}'.format(func.__name__))
            missing = self.required.difference(kwargs['params'])
            if missing:
                raise ValueError('Missing from "params" dictionary in "{0}": {1}'.format(func.__name__, ', '.join(sorted(missing))))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was add *args, **kwargs, and just check for the keys that are required within the 'params' argument via kwargs['params'] after checking that kwargs params exists.

Here's the new version (which works perfectly):

```
class requiresparams(object):
    """

    Used as a decorator with an iterable passed in, this will look for each item
    in the iterable given as a key in the params argument of the function being
    decorated. It was built for a series of PayPal methods that require
    different params, and AOP was the best way to handle it while staying DRY.


    >>> @requiresparams(['name', 'pass', 'code'])
    ... def complex_function(params):
    ...     print(params['name'])
    ...     print(params['pass'])
    ...     print(params['code'])
    >>> 
    >>> params = {
    ...     'name': 'John Doe',
    ...     'pass': 'OpenSesame',
    ...     #'code': '1134',
    ... }
    >>> 
    >>> complex_function(params=params)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: Missing from "params" dictionary: code
    """
    def __init__(self, required):
        self.required = set(required)

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not kwargs.get('params', None):
                raise KeyError('"params" kwarg required for {0}'.format(func.__name__))
            missing = self.required.difference(kwargs['params'])
            if missing:
                raise ValueError('Missing from "params" dictionary: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(missing)))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 2):

`def wrapper(params):` means you're only going to accept one argument -- and so of course calls with `(self, params)` just won't work.  You need to be able to accept either one or two arguments, e.g., at the very least (if you don't need to support calls w/named args):

```
def wrapper(one, two=None):
  if two is None: params = one
  else: params = two
  # and the rest as above
```

You can get much more complex / sophisticated in order to also accept named arguments, but this is much simpler and still "mostly works";-).

Comment: Oh, no no. 'params' is the name of a dictionary argument. It takes just one argument. See the doctest included.

Comment: @orokusaki, when you write `def foo(self, params):`, those are **TWO** arguments, not one -- count them.  Your failure to acknowledge this is what is causing the bug in your code: you **have** to accept being called with either one or two args, and your `def wrapper`, as coded, just doesn't (it forces a single argument, just like you think it should... and you're wrong, Python is telling you that, and so am I;-).

Comment: Did you see my question Alex? How do I get the decorator to work for a method of a class and a normal function without having two versions of the decorator. I'm not a complete noob. I just don't understand how to make a version for instance methods and functions.

Comment: @orokusaki  It's like Alex puts it.  I think the confusion is only in Alex' choice of parameter names for the two-arguments form of the decorator.  In your example 'one' and 'two' are passed within a dictionary, and this dictionary is the only argument that really matters.  Alex used one and two to signify _completely_ different things.  Imagine he had written then as, say,  `def wrapper(FirstArg, PossibleSecondArg=None)`.

Comment: @orokusaki, the code I give for `wrapper` **does** work for both methods and standalone functions without having two versions -- have you **tried** it, instead of endlessly carping about it?-)

Comment: If somebody asks: "How do I fix my muffler?", the answer shouldn't be "Don't use a muffler. Instead use straight pipes.".

Comment: @Omnifarious: exactly -- your answer's very general, mine is perfectly specific to @orokusaki's **exact** problem -- though he refuses to understand this makes my answer _better_ for his specific problem!-)

@orokusaki, I'm **not** telling you "what not to do": I'm fixing your exact, specific problem -- and you're apparently totally blind to the fact that I did: ah well, **your** personality problem, **not** mine!-)

Comment: Dude, Alex. I appreciate your help for real. I figured out a solution and I think it's much more Pythonic is all. You don't have to get angry with people who don't understand your approach. You're clearly a computer scientist and not all the rest of us are (yet).

Comment: @orokusaki, I've never been a computer scientist (though wikipedia keeps claiming I am and I can't get them to fix it) -- I'm an engineer. It's just ridiculous to see on your Q you claiming "I know how to use `*args`, `**kwargs`, et al. I don't need that" and then see you posting a self-answer starting with "What I did was add `*args`, `**kwargs`,"... plus, your solution is just wrong, and does **not** do what you claim it does (if `params` is passed in as a positional argument, as in your docstring's example, your `wrapper` fails -- you only support named-argument `params`!). Blech.

Comment: I actually fixed my docstring right after I posted that on there (only after doc testing it). Remember my original approach was to use a positional argument. I never updated my doc string but I updated my code. The only thing that is blech is the attitude. I have the utmost respect for you as a programmer. However, you have a cocky attitude (not to mention that the example above is very implicit in style (allowing for a possible run time error if an incorrect argument was passed into the method) and Python's own guide says "Explicit of implicit"). I posted my own version since it was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Decorators normally look like this:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
    # Pull what you need out of the argument lists and do stuff with it
    func(*args, **kargs)
```

Then they work with any function passed to them, not just functions with a specific number of arguments or with specific keyword arguments.  In this specific case, you may want to do some introspection on the func passed to `__call__` to find out if it's a one or two argument function and to make sure the last argument is called 'params'.  Then just write `wrapper` like this:

```
def wrapper(*args):
    params = args[-1]
    missing = self.required.difference(params)
    if missing:
        raise ValueError('Missing from "params" argument: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(missing)))
    func(params)
```

Comment: Thanks Omnifarious. I ended up using *args, **kwargs instead but your answer got me thinking in the right direction.